# activerecord flag on creation but doesn't get saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an active record model and want a way to have an attribute that gets passed in on creation but isn't a row in the database. Basically, it will determine whether a logging record gets created in another table.

I was thinking something like this:

```
Item.create!({:header_id => 17, :header => 'here is my value', :position => 13.125, :created_from_inventory => true })
```

The :created_from_inventory doesn't exist in db but will be used in a callback.

Any ideas on how to do this?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the item model

```
attr_accessor :created_from_inventory
```

It will add a non db attribute to your model.  It will exist as long as the instance exists. once the instance goes out of scope it will be lost.